# SSRS format rows on report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-grouping

I have a simple report that groups rows on PERSON then on DATE. I have these two groups in the grouping pane with the DETAILS GROUP below.

The trouble with this is that I end up with PERSON AND DATE appearing at the top of the first 2 columns on the left, but the rest of these two columns are just empty space which is wasting a lot of space on the left hand side of the page.

How can I format so that I keep the same grouping but have the PERSON and DATE appearing together on the first row only with all other data displayed below. This grouping would then show again as a single row whenever the group changes (which it does at the moment, but with loads of dead space on the page on the left hand side)

I've tried adding a 'column group' of PERSON AND DATE, but this ends up with the report being massive horizontally.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could put your table control inside a list control and give them both the same datasource and grouping. Then put your PERSON and DATE fields in the list control and position them as you like. The table would only be there to display the detail and wouldn't have fields for PERSON and DATE.

Answer (score 0):

Just Right click on the Grouping Column that was automatically added on the Tablix, and Delete that Column.
And, You have additional Two rows (Group header) above the Detail row : Person Group, and Date Group.
Simply, Select the Cells inside that Row, and Right click and Merge So, that you only have a Single Cell inside the Group Header. And, Write an expression inside that Cell according to your Group Header Requirement i.e. If you want to Show Person : PersonName in Group header of Person Group Then, Merge and Right click on that cell and Goto Expression then Type :

="Client : " + DataSet!Fields!FieldName

Do, the Same for the Another Date Group.

I hope you understoood.